# Put serializable into intent not working

Tags: android

I put in intent my object with following code (while putting list does exists, I checked in debugger)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("product", CategoryActivity.this.list.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And then retrive

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
product = (Product) intent.getSerializableExtra("product");
```

But it is null

Model class is following

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    Integer pk;
    String name;
    String description;
    Integer price;
    String image_url;
    List<Option> options;

    public Product(Integer pk, String name, String description, Integer price, String image_url, List<Option> options) {
        this.pk = pk;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.options = options;
    }

    public Integer getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(Integer pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you also check that list.get(position) is not returning null?

Comment: Are you restarting an already started activity with `startActivity(intent)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more code to use your class inside intent data.

```
        import android.os.Parcel;
        import android.os.Parcelable;

        public class Yourclass implements Parcelable {
        //your code

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        //e.g.
            out.writeInt(this.getWhat());
        //similar code
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }


    private YourClass(Parcel in) {
    //e.g.
        this.setWhat(in.readInt());
        }

public static final Parcelable.Creator<YourClass> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<YourClass>() {

public YourClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new YourClass(in);
    }

public YourClass[] newArray(int size) {
        return new YourClass[size];
    }
};
        }
```

to store use `intent.putExtra(EXTRANAME, obj);` to retrieve use `YourClass myObj = (YourClass) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRANAME);`

Comment: do you mean that using Parcelable instead of Serialializable is not just best practice but that Serializable doesn't actually work?

Comment: @lelloman , i found that such solution can work for data transfer inside intent

Comment: it does work, it is also a best practice to use Parcelable instead of Serializable on Android. However, I think that Serializable should work just fine, Intent has `putExtra(String, Serializable)` and `getSerializableExtra(String)` methods

Comment: how to get object in target activity ?